# Unable to wake up after locking screen

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, lock, screensaver, acer

Just installed Xubuntu 19.04. When I try to lock my screen it does some weird and crashes. Screen turns off and I have to turn the system off manually. Tried xscreensaver and it works just fine, but I like the look of lightdm so I want to keep using it.

```
    lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

uname -a
Linux n40033 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 17:41:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lscpu 
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               142
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             823.415
CPU max MHz:         4000,0000
CPU min MHz:         400,0000
BogoMIPS:            3984.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d


BIOS Information
    Vendor: Insyde Corp.
    Version: V1.00
    Release Date: 08/17/2018
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
```

Notebook: TravelMate X3410-M

Comment: On my Kubuntu 16.04 I had a similar problem, and I found I could just use the screen lightness keys to light up the screen and use the waiting screen locker. Not sure it's you problem but very easy to test.

Comment: Screen turns completly off. Nothing is able to bring it back on. Backlid of keyboard seems to react okay to pressing keys, but does not wake up the system/ or turns on display.

Comment: Temporary workaround for me was to change locking screen to suspending. All works good and is almost as fast as locking screem , since I am running od M,2 SSD. Still looking for proper solution.